# A C program that counts the letters in each word and displays frequency of words with same letters length, tell me where I am wrong

Tags: c, for-loop, debugging

Please help me find the error in this basic c program. I am a beginner.
The program counts the number of letters in each word, then should display the frequency of each letter word being repeated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ int lenCount[20], i, c, state;
  for(i=0; i<=20; i++)
  lenCount[i]=0;
  printf("Enter the words:\n");
  while((c=getchar()!=EOF)) {
    if(c=='\n'||c==' '||c=='\t'){
      lenCount[i] = lenCount[i] +1;
      i = 0;
    }
    else {
      ++i;

    }  
    }
  
  for(i=0; i<=20; i++){
  printf("\n Words with %d letters are repeated %d times", i, lenCount[i]);}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thefirststepindebuggingisindentingyourcodecorrectlysoitbecomesreadableandthereforemaintainable

Comment: First thing to do: apply a consistent formatting/indenting. Readability is most important, especially for beginners

Comment: Also read this: [ask]. Especially you need to show at least one example of input along with expected vs. actual output.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this hastebin here for anyone trying to parse through what OP's code is doing for now. https://hastebin.com/itulasamuq.cpp . Can't edit directly because it's rude and because it has minor consistency edits.

Comment: @Daksh If a character is not a '\n', ' ', '\t', that does not mean it must be a letter. Research isalpha().

Comment: @Daksh, `printf("\n Words with %d letters ...` displays all length frequencies.  "displays frequency of words with same letters length" sounds like to display only need if the frequency was more 2 or more.

Comment: @Daksh you have an off by one error when you do `i <= 20`, since the bounds of your array are [0, 19] inclusive(and lenCount[20] is an out of bounds 21st element). Your concept of "repeated" isn't clear, I am guessing you meant "There were %d words with length %d."(but I am not sure).